# button_to helper for invalid comments in Rails 4 throws 'No route matches'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In this system, you can post questions and comment on them, and it uses the [acts_as_votable](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable) gem so that users can upvote/downvote the comments. I'd like to show a button for the upvote/downvote, rather than a link, so I did this in the view:

```
<h2>Comments</h2>
<% @question.comments.order('cached_votes_up DESC').each do |comment| %>
  <% unless comment.errors.any? %>
  <p><strong>Commenter:</strong> <%= comment.user.username %></p>
  <p><strong>Comment:</strong><%= comment.body %></p>

  <%= button_to_if !comment.new_record?, 'Upvote', {
    :action => 'upvote',
    :controller => 'comments',
    :question => {
      :question_id => @question.id
    },
    :comment => comment.id
  },
  :class => 'btn btn-default' %>

  <%= button_to_if !comment.new_record?, 'Downvote', {
    :action => 'downvote',
    :controller => 'comments',
    :question => {
      :question_id => @question.id
    },
    :comment => comment.id
  },
  :class => 'btn btn-default' %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>

<h2>Add a comment</h2>

<% if @comment && @comment.errors.any? %>
  <% @comment.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
<%= form_for([@question, @question.comments.build]) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :body %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Now, everything works great when comments are *valid*. But, Rails throws an error when the comment has been submitted but is *invalid*:

```
No route matches {
    :action=> "upvote",
    :comment=> 3,
    :controller=> "comments",
    :question=> {
        :question_id=> 2
    },
    :question_id=> "2-test-question"
}
```

This is because the comment for the question does not have an ID yet because it was invalid, and therefore hasn't been saved to the database. Yet, it is still being counted in the collection of comments that are rendered in the view. Wrapping the button code with the `<% unless comment.errors.any? %>` didn't seem to do anything.

Initially, I had the `button_to` helper to create the buttons, but as it wasn't working, I tried wrapping that with a `button_to_if` helper, so that it could evaluate a condition before rendering the button. Unfortunately, everything I tried evaluated to true. The helper code is:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  # Render the button only if the condition evaluates to true
  def button_to_if (condition, name = nil, options = nil, html_options = nil, &block)
    if condition
      button_to(name, options, html_options, &block)
    end
  end
end
```

The relevant method from the comments controller to create comments:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def create
    @question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
    @comment = @question.comments.build(comment_params)
    @comment.userid = current_user.id
    if @comment.save
      redirect_to @question
    else
      render 'questions/show'
    end
  end

  private
    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:author, :body)
    end
end
```

The comment model has just simple `presence` and `length` validation. I know that's working fine. The problem seems to be in the `button_to` helper but for the life of me I can't figure out what's wrong. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the error is cause by invalid comments? `comment=> 3` in error message makes it looks like comment has id (3)?

Comment: Yes, I get this error when submitting a blank/too short comment; it's all OK if the comment met the `length` requirement.

Comment: so how does this comment have id? :)

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest, because the comment has not yet been saved; if I were to put `<%= debug @comments %>` in the view and take the `button_to_if` out, I can see a collection of comments, and the one I posted does not have an ID. It's strange, do you think it could be the auto-increment from the table? In any case, the button should not be rendered as the comment should have errors and therefore should not pass the `yield` test.

Comment: Meant `<% unless comment.errors.any? %>` rather than `yield` :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a routing error; `:id` was not defined in the `button_to` hash, and so Rails could not route it properly. Weird that it was only showing after comments had been posted though.